# Subclassing from BasicButtonUI - text is rendered, but no border nor background

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, look-and-feel

I am trying to extend UI on some instances of JButton. The text and my test lines are visible, but no standard JButton border nor background for system LaF (Windows in my case). Only Motif works fine (see at the bottom).

```
JButton m_button = new JButton ();
QButtonUI m_ui = QButtonUI.createUI(m_button);
...

public class QButtonUI extends BasicButtonUI {
    public QButtonUI() {
    }
    
    public static QButtonUI createUI(JButton c) {
        QButtonUI ui = new QButtonUI();
        c.setUI(ui);
        return ui;
    }
    
    protected void paintButtonPressed(Graphics g, AbstractButton b) {
        super.paintButtonPressed(g, b);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(0, 0, 20, 20);
    }
    
    public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        super.update(g, c);
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.drawLine(0, 20, 20, 0);
    }
}
```

In fact:

- WindowsLookAndFeel and NimbusLookAndFeel don't work - no border and no background, just text.
- Default (metal) and WindowsClassic: have border but no background (not sure if WindowsClassic has a background)
- Motif works fine and looks great

Looks like an incomplete implementation but I'll leave the question in case I missed a call or param.

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
//UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
//UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
//UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");
//UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
//UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel");
```

Comment: Extending a "Basic" UI class is a problem because you lose the customization of each LAF. For example, the Metal LAF uses the MetalButtonUI, which extends BasicButtonUI. So, by replacing the MetalButtonUI, you lose all the metal customizations for the button. If you really need to do customizations, then you need to extend the MetalButtonUI and each UI for the LAF you want to support.

Comment: Great, thanks. Metal works fine now. I guess I made similar mistake in others.

Comment: @camickr - can we promote your comment to answer so I can accept it(haven't used this system in years)

Comment: You really should be installing the UI delegate onto the button control, as apposed to calling the delegates `create` method manually - won't change you problem, it's just how it should be used